# Spring batch: alternative to JpaPagingItemReader which causes ORA-01555

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a batch job with two steps

1. **Step 1:** Go to external database, call stored proc, compose jpa entities and persist them into internal database with the flag NOT_PROCESSED.
2. **Step 2:** Loop through just saved entities with flag NOT_PROCESSED, process them and write updated entity back (doesn't update the flag)

Once all of them are processed the flag for all of them is updated to PROCESSED. I.e. update all or nothing.

The step 1 is ok and works pretty smooth.

The step 2 is basically JpaPagingItemReader with pageSize=4, set of processors(mostly http calls) and JpaItemWriter with commit-interval=1. (I know that it is recommended to have pageSize equal to commit-interval, it's just what I have) It is also a multithreaded step with 10 threads doing the job.

That said on the step 2 I have two kind of queries:

1. Read: `select * from ENTITY where processed=false order by id` nested into two queries for paging `select ... from (select .. where rownum < M) where rownum >= N`
2. Write: `update ENTITY set .. where id = ID`

For some reason when I have enough entities I get infamous:

> Ora-01555, snapshot too old: rollback segment with name ""
>   too small

I don't know exact reason of that error (undo stat doesn't show anything bad, so hopefully DBAs will find the culprit soon), but in the meantime I think that what read query does is terribly bad. Such paging queries are hard for a database anyway, but I guess when you read and at the same time update the entries which you read it may cause that kind of errors.

I would like to change the approach taken in the step 2. Instead of reading in pages. I would like to read all the ids into memory **only once**(i.e. give me ids of all entities I need to process) and then give each thread the id from that list. The first processor in chain will get the entity by the id through JPA. That way I continue to update and write entities one-by-one and at the same time I read the ids I need only once.

My problem is I couldn't find out-of the box solution for such reader. Is there anything I can use for that?

Comment: Why don't you execute both select+update as a single SQL statement? Also what is you isolation level?

Comment: Because to get values for update there is a very complicated logic, if I oversimplify - the update depends on external service calls. Default for oracle, afair it's read commited.

Comment: You can get this error for two main reasons, 1st when you modify lobs, 2nd the your query execution takes too much time. The "too much" is usually defined as column TUNED_UNDORETENTION from the view v$undostat. This will show what is reasonable undo retention for your database, with particular UNDO tbs size, and particular transactional activity.

Comment: Updates set the lob field(xml response of external service ~12Kb at max) and it may be one of culprits, however  as it reads entities without that lob, and inserting the lobs per each entry in single transaction I don't understand how it may cause the issue. Again, I am not an Oracle expert, so it's hard for me to say what is wrong, but I know that paging query here is definitely bad, especially when concurrent updates rewrite the blocks which were just read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I implemented the solution by myself and it is based on [this](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/91168-thread-synchronization-issue-in-jdbccursoritemreader) and [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/SynchronizedItemStreamReader.html). In fact I didn't use those directly, but my implementation is quite close.

Basically, this is how it looks (I don't have the code, so using my memory)

```
public class MyUnprocessedIdReader extends AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader<Long> {

    private final Object lock = new Object();

    private initialized = false;

    private final MyObjectsRepository repo;

    private List<Long> ids; 

    private int current = -1;

    public MyUnprocessedIdReader(MyObjectsRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public void doOpen() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            Assert.state(!initialized, "Cannot open an already opened ItemReader, call close first");

            this.initialized = true;
            this.ids = ImmutableList.copyOf(repo.findAllUnprocessed());
        }
    }

    public Long doRead() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            if (ids == null || !initialized) {
             throw new IllegalStateException("Have you opened the reader?");
            }

            ++current;
            if (current < ids.size()) {
                return ids.get(current);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }

    public void doClose() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            this.initialized = false;
            this.current = -1;
            this.ids = null;
        }    
    }
}
```

My repository is using JPA so under the hood it uses something like `entityManager.createQuery("select obj.id from Objects where obj.processed = false order by obj.id asc", Long.class).executeSelect()`

Also I have added one more processor to the chain:

```
public class LoadProcessor implements ItemProcessor<Long, MyObject> {
    private final MyObjectsRepository repo;

    public LoadProcessor(MyObjectsRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    public MyObject process(Long id) {
        return repo.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Someone may say that it is less scalable than using cursor, also there is a contention on read method, however it is very simple solution which do its job well until the number of unprocessed ids is too huge. Also processing threads are spending a lot of time in calling external REST services, so the contention on read won't be a bottleneck ever.

P.s. later I will give an update on whether it solved the issue with ORA-01555 or not.